# SQL IN Operator Long String

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

This is my code

```
ids = df['id'] #id column from pandas DataFrame
query = f"SELECT * FROM Members WHERE id IN {tuple(ids.value)}"
result = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

My Problem:
There are lots of ids in df['id']. It changes but generally more than 100k. Therefore it gives SQL error, if it doesn't it takes too long to give the result. Is there any other way for me to achieve what I want or it's not possible?

Comment: Hi @votka. Just create a table to keep all the ids

Comment: Hi @ekochergin. Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I don't have permission to create tables.

Comment: Hi,Seperate Ids  to some Array ,then execute query with loop

Comment: @votka that's sad. I'm not famliar with pandas. an you perhaps join members table with a dataframe or with it's data source?